# Inserting Hebrew text into mysql using php - blank

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a problem when I upload csv file to mysql. 
I used this code:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $c = 0;
    $row=1;

    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        if ($row ==1) {
            $row++;
            continue;
        }
        $name = $filesop[0];
        $phone = $filesop[1];

        $sql = runsql("INSERT INTO messages_recipient (user_id,full_name, phone,date_added) VALUES ($SVARS[user_id],'$name','$phone',NOW())");
    }

    if($sql) {
        echo "You database has imported successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
    }
}
```

it's worked fine except when i upload csv file with hebrew values i get blank values in mysql.
i tried to change the type to text/long text without success.
the collation is: utf8_general_ci.
thanks for the help

Comment: @PedroLobito I was about to google that.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari I did...it doesn't return anything...

Comment: it's a function of the cms i working on, the function connect me to the db.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for:

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

and

```
mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8 ");
```

---

### Use it before the query.

mysqli.set-charset:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Did you **check** the values before`insert`? Are you sure they aren't empty ?

Comment: what do i mean by check the values?

Comment: `VALUES ($SVARS[user_id],'$name','$phone',NOW())");`

Comment: yes, i checked the values they aren't empty,and when i replace the $name value from Hebrew to English it's worked fine.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @talazouri make sure that the csv file is utf-8 encoded as well as your php script.also have you tried just to output the text and see what happens ?